# Simple way to limit the output to a certain integer without using if/else statements?

Tags: java, variables, return, limit, return-value

I have an assignment where I need to calculate grades. The block of code below takes the user inputted "sections" and multiplies it by 4, while limiting the total output to 20. According to the assignment, we can't use if/else statements, but that's all I can think of to limit the output to 20. Perhaps using a simple Math method? But I can't think of a simple way to do this.

```
 public static int calcDGrade(int sections) //method to calculate the grade for the students sections
{
      int maxDGrade = ((sections*4)); 

      if (maxDGrade > 20) //limits total score to 20

            {
                 return 20;
            } 
      else 
            { 
                 return maxDGrade;
            }

}
```

Comment: `Math.min` and/or `Math.max`

Comment: I thought about this, but I'm not sure how to utilize them in the way that I need. I know max and min output the highest and lowest of the of a set of integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
return maxDGrade > 20 ? 20 : maxDGrade;
```

The ternary operation consists of the following parts:

```
condition ? A : B
```

where A is the result of the operation if the condition evaluates to `true`, and `B` is the result if the condition evaluates to `false`.

For your example, it will return `20` if `maxDGrade` is greater than 20, otherwise it will return the value of `maxDGrade`. In other words, it's equivalent to saying:

```
if (maxDGrade > 20) {
    return 20;
} else {
    return maxDGrade;
}
```

Comment: So basically remove the if/else statement and use that? What exactly does the ternary operator do?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) to get the minimum of 20 and your other value. Something like

```
int maxDGrade = Math.min(20, sections*4);
```

Because you want `20` or the result of the multiplication, which ever is *lower*.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I needed. So simple, I didn't think to put a math equation inside of Math.min().